Delay in obtaining data from Chrome extentin when using sendMessage feature
I am currently creating a Google Chrome extension, but I encountered some problems when requesting a connection between content.js and background.ks.
I am sending a message from content.js containing an external link to background.js.
When the link reaches the service worker, bachground.js performs a fetch() for this link and extracts the information
My problem is that the fetch() process takes some time to finish, and when the onMessage property sends the fetch data back to sendMesage, I  get undefinde
so, how i fix this
